# According to Newton's law of cooling, the temperature $T$ of an object at time $t$ is given by...

Tags: probability, statistics, physics

According to Newton's law of cooling, the temperature $T$ of an object at time $t$ is given by $T = T_A + (T_0 - T_A)e^{-kt}$, where $T_A$ is the ambient temperature and $T_0$ is the initial temperature, and $k$ is the cooling rate constant. For a certain type of beverage container, the value of $k$ is known to be $0.025 \text{ min}^{-1}$

Assume that $T_{A} = 36^{\circ}$F exactly and that $T_0$ varies with mean $= 72^{\circ}$F and standard deviation $= 0.5^{\circ}$F. Find mean of $T$ and standard deviation of $T$ at time $t = 10$.

I know this is a physics problem but I got this problem from my statistics class and I have no idea how to approach this. What distribution model am I supposed to use here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expected value (i.e. mean) is a linear operator. This means we can write:

$$\langle T \rangle = \langle T_A + (T_0 - T_A)e^{-kt}\rangle =  \langle T_A \rangle + \langle T_0 e^{-kt} \rangle - \langle T_Ae^{-kt} \rangle =  T_A + \langle T_0 \rangle e^{-kt} - T_A e^{-kt}$$
(Try to think about why this would work from a conceptual standpoint. Adding in and multiplying by constants will just shift and re-scale the mean).

Standard deviation can be defined as:
$$\sigma = \sqrt{\langle T^2 \rangle - \langle T \rangle ^2}$$

Do you see how to finish?

Comment: i dont think my professor ever talked about this, so im completely confused. I know what you did with the equation, but i don't understand how you got the equation for sigma. By the way, am i expected to plug in 36 for Ta and 72 for To, and 0.025 for k?

Comment: That is a relatively common expression for the standard deviation of a random variable. Yes, I would imagine you should plug in the given values at the end.